# How i can use functions in multiple files, c++

Tags: c++, function, file

I have a little problem with using multiple files.
I have a task to use three files: **function.h**, **function.cpp**, **prog.cpp**.

In *function.h* I defined each function.

In *function.cpp* I put the code of each function.

In *prog.cpp* I have to call the functions. There i don't have anything defined.

I have these errors:

```
"void __cdecl randInt(int *,int)" (?randInt@@YAXPAHH@Z) already defined in function.obj

"void __cdecl showInt(int *,int)" (?showInt@@YAXPAHH@Z) already defined in function.obj

One or more multiply defined symbols found
```

**function.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void randInt(int *arr, int size) {
    for (int *i = arr; i < arr + size; i++) {
        *i = rand() % 10;
    }

}
void showInt(int *arr, int size) {
    cout << "Int Massive" << endl;
    for (int *i = arr; i < arr + size; i++) {
        cout << *i << ", ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

**function.h:**

```
#pragma once
void randInt(int *, int);
void showInt(int *, int);
```

**prog.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>;
using namespace std;
#include "function.h"
#include "function.cpp"


int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int n = 10;
    int *arrInt = new int[10];
    randInt(&arrInt[0], n);
    showInt(&arrInt[0], n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `prog.cpp` explicitly includes `function.cpp`. That's your problem.

Comment: Remove `#include "function.cpp"`

Comment: _In function.h I defined each function._ - You *declared* the functions. _In function.cpp I put the code of each function._ - You *defined* the functions. To call the functions from anywhere, you only need the *declarations*. So you should only include the header file where these declarations are.

Comment: Include `#include function.cpp` in `function.h` file and remove as `#include function.cpp` mentioned in above comments or Try using `#ifndef`. `#ifndef` checks whether the given token has been #defined earlier in the file or in an included file; if not, it includes the code between it

Comment: @daemon7osh You misunderstand something. One doesn't normally include `*.cpp` in a `*.h`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is incorrect and unnecessary to include the **.cpp** file, so remove `#include "function.cpp"` and you should be fine.

Comment: @chbchb55 Only removing  `#include " function.cpp"` will lead to undefined reference to function. Include your  `function.cpp` file into .h file

Comment: @daemon7osh @chbchb55 Including `*.cpp` in a `*.h` makes zero sense. OP just needs to remove `#include "function.cpp"` and that's all.

Comment: Your original answer was correct, but now I don't think it is.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat if `function.cpp` file is no included anywhere in the code where will be the function definition? Adding only declaration to `prog.cpp` gave me `undefined reference function` while linking.

Comment: @daemon7osh Any large C++ generally has multiple `.cpp` files. Every C++ compiler supports building a single executable from _multiple_ `.cpp` files. You don't need to include them anywhere to do it. You just need to configure your project properly and your error will go away.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat got your point. Edited answer waiting for peer-review.

Comment: @daemon7osh I rolled the answer back to the original version, since you don't need to include `function.h` in `function.cpp` here. It causes no harm and the code will work without it too.

Answer (score 0):

You should edit your file in this way

**function.h**

```
    #pragma once
    void randInt(int *, int);
    void showInt(int *, int);
```

**fuction.cpp**

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "function.h"
    using namespace std;

    void randInt(int *arr, int size) {
        for (int *i = arr; i < arr + size; i++) {
            *i = rand() % 10;
        }

    }
    void showInt(int *arr, int size) {
        cout << "Int Massive" << endl;
        for (int *i = arr; i < arr + size; i++) {
            cout << *i << ", ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

**prg.cpp**

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <ctime>;
    #include "function.h"
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        srand(time(0));
        int n = 10;
        int *arrInt = new int[10];
        randInt(&arrInt[0], n);
        showInt(&arrInt[0], n);
        return 0;
     }
```

Then you can compile your program by linking the prg.cpp with your function.cpp file. If your are using g++ compiler you can do so in way given below.

```
    g++ prg.cpp fuction.cpp
```